# Why absolute value difference test does not give correct results in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, if-statement

I have a gray-scale image read in MATLAB and I want to calculate the ratio of how many pixels have the same value or different from their left neighbors by absolute threshold differences [0,1,3]. Initially I was using the following code:

```
[row,col] = size(processed_map);
flagged_map = zeros(row,col);

for thres = [0,1,3]

    cnt = 0;
    for i=1:row
        if (mod(i, 10) == 0)

            %fprintf('Line %i is processed .\n', i); 
        end
        
        for j =2:col
           
            left_n = processed_map(i,j-1);
            current = processed_map(i,j);    
                            
            if(abs(left_n - current) <= thres)
                fprintf('Current Pixel Value = %i , its neighbour value = %i \n',current,left_n);
                cnt = cnt + 1;
                flagged_map(i,j) = 1;


            end
 
        end

    end
      format long g  
      Ratio = round(100 * cnt/(row * (col-1)),2);

     
     fprintf('DELTA = %i : %.2f \n',thres,Ratio);
      
end
```

For a threshold value of '0', meaning I am looking for same neighbor values. When it enters the 'if condition of same value' I am getting some printed statements outputs as

```
Current Pixel Value = 118 , its neighbour value = 53 
Current Pixel Value = 119 , its neighbour value = 118
```

Which is not correct of course! And I could not figure why! However when I use the following if

statement for threshold = 0

```
if(left_n == current)
```

All entered current & left_n pixels are as expected. Same errors occur for other threshold absolute conditions when written as the given code.

Comment: Please read [mre]. We cannot run your code and reproduce your problem because some variables are undefined. But my guess is that `processed_map` is an unsigned integer type. The subtraction of two unsigned integers is 0 if the second operand is larger (saturated arithmetic). You should always convert data to a floating-point type to avoid that type of issues.

Comment: I think you are right Cris, my processed_map is 'uint16' type. Now when I converted it to 'single' type it gives me the correct ratio. Many thanks! I will try with the other thresholds as well, I did not now anything about saturated arithmetic for MATLAB coding :(